# Como faço para unir uma list no Python?

Tags: python, lista

Quando quero unir um `array` no PHP, eu utilizo a função `array_merge()`

Assim:

```
$a = [1, 2, 3];

$b = [4, 5, 6];

array_merge($a, $b);
```

Resultado:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

E como eu poderia fazer isso em Python numa *list* (acho que uma *list* equivale ao *array* no PHP, se não estou enganado)?

Exemplo:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

b = [4, 5, 6];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pode simplesmente adicionar as duas:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
print (a + b)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/uKMSCP). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Concatpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/Concat.py).

Python sobrecarrega os operadores tanto quanto possível para tornar mais intuitivo e curto. Alguns discordam que isto é mais intuitivo mas muitos acham bem óbvio.

Só não esqueça que não tem `;` em Pyhton :)

Comment: Eu sempre esqueço que não estou no PHP! há problemas se eu esquecer um `;` lá no código?

Comment: É aceito sem causar problemas porque você pode querer colocar vários *statements* em uma mesma linha. Mas fica esquisito usar no fim da linha simples.

Comment: _... Já que no python a organização é feita pela identação..._ Completo a frase

Comment: O CloudFlare tá me sacaneando hoje, eu fico atrasado porque não consegue acessar o site. Já faz quase uma semana. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4225/101

Answer (score 9):

Você pode usar o `extend()`. Exemplo:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
a.extend(b)
print a
```

Resultado:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Mais informações sobre os métodos de listas: [Pythons Docs - Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: Achei que você ia responder outra coisa, mas foi bom conhecer o `extend`

Comment: Como assim "outra coisa"? rs.. Não entendi se a solução atende ou não.

Comment: Não, atende sim, amigo, @Math. Achei que você ia responder o `+`. Muito bom, eu não sabia que podia fazer isso

Comment: No caso, seria como + para criar uma variável `c` com os dois valores, sem alterar a original?

Comment: Ah, ótimo :) Agora tb eu entendi o que quer dizer por "mudar a maneira de exibir o resultado"

Comment: Espero que entenda que marquei a resposta do @bigown por conta da questão de manter a variável original com o mesmo valor :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sem problemas cara! Tem que marcar a que melhor lhe atende mesmo :)